# Adding Announcement to Napili Template

Tags: community, chatter-groups, napili

I wanted to know if the Announcements feature that is available is chatter Groups can be implemented or added to the Community created via the Napili template as a base.

I dont want to create a group (Coz i know that will enable it) But is there a way to do it with out using groups?

Also if not, is it possible if we create a community page using VF and Apex?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Group Announcements are not supported yet in Napili .Here is the document [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_networks_templates_groups_napili.htm) saying it is not available in Spring 16 .

While this is certainly available in your communities built with VF + Tabs .

Also note that you can build lightning components for your feature in Napili.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this feature as well which looks like in Beta and a part of Spring 16.

Though you will need to enable it from support.
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_chatter_group_send_announcement_emails.htm